# Gatsby site unavailable during build time

Tags: node.js, gatsby, yarnpkg

I serve my Gatsby `/public` directory via nginx. During a new build process, my site is therefore unavailable. The files in this directory are deleted and rebuild.  Build times can take quite long. I don’t like that.

Any tips on how to mitigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my solution is not to serve the `/public` folder directly.

After the build is finished, it is copied to a `/pre` folder which takes about 11ms. The old `/live` folder is then renamed and replaced by the `/pre` folder. That takes about 35.125µs. Much better than the 10-30 seconds of build time of Gatsby, in which the site was not reliably available.